# How to respond correctly to an AJAX call in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to update form fields using `ajax` and `php`.

My AJax call is like this :

```
var productId = 'productId=' + id;

$.ajax({
  url: './includes/process_edit_products.php',
  method: 'post',
  data: productId
}).success(function(response) {
  // Populate the form fields with the data returned from server
  $('#userForm')
    .find('[name="product_id"]').val(response.product_id).end()
    .find('[name="product_name"]').val(response.product_name).end()
    .find('[name="product_price"]').val(response.product_price).end()
    .find('[name="product_des"]').val(response.product_des).end();

  // Show the dialog
  bootbox
    .dialog({
      title: 'Edit Products',
      message: $('#userForm'),
      show: false // We will show it manually later
    })
    .on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $('#userForm')
        .show() // Show the login form
        .formValidation('resetForm'); // Reset form
    })
    .on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
      $('#userForm').hide().appendTo('body');
    })
    .modal('show');
});
```

PHP processing script is like this:

```
if ((isset($_POST['productId'])) && (is_numeric($_POST['productId'])) ) { // Form submission.
    $productId = (int)$_POST['productId'];
    //echo $productId;

        // fetch the selected product to edit
    $query = " SELECT product_id, product_name, price, product_des
                         FROM  product
                         WHERE product_id = ? LIMIT 1";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    if ($stmt) {
        // Bind "$imageId" to parameter.
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $productId);  
        // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->execute();    
        $stmt->store_result();
        // count rows
        $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;

        if ($numrows == 1) {
            // get variables from result.
            $stmt->bind_result($product_id, $product_name, $price, $product_des);   

        // Fetch all the records:
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            //echo $product_id;
            //echo $product_name;
        //echo $price;
        //echo $product_des;

            //$response = array('product_id' => $product_id, 'product_name' => $product_name, 'product_price' => $price, 'product_des') => $product_des;
            //echo json_encode($Response);

            $resultArray['product_id'] = $product_id;
            $resultArray['product_name'] = $product_name;
            $resultArray['price'] = $price;
            $resultArray['product_des'] = $product_des;
            echo json_encode($resultArray);
        }   

            // Close the statement:
            $stmt->close();
            unset($stmt);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is I am not sure how to get php processing data back and populate the form fields with existing data.

Can anybody tell what do I need to do in my php.

Comment: You seem to be expecting `response` in your success callback to be a JSON object, but your PHP script merely echoes a couple of strings (`$product_id`, `$product_name`, etc.). Make an array with all the relevant data and json_encode it.

Comment: @Huey, Can You kindly show me how I edit my php accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @SMcCrohan When editing a post; please do remove unnecessary phrases like "Thanks", "Hi" etc. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/212576

Comment: @Huey, I tried it but seems not working. can you tell me how I use this - `response = jQuery.parseJSON(response)`

Comment: And also I tried it like this way `    $response = array('product_id' => $product_id, 'product_name' => $product_name, 'product_price' => $price, 'product_des') => $product_des;
    echo json_encode($Response);
    `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be expecting response in your `success` callback to be a JSON object, but your PHP script merely echoes a couple of strings (`$product_id`, `$product_name`, etc.). Make an array with all the relevant data and `json_encode` it.

```
$resultArray = array();
while{
    ...
    $curProduct['product_id'] = $product_id;
    $curProduct['product_name'] = $product_name;
    $curProduct['price'] = $price;
    $curProduct['product_des'] = $product_des;
    $resultArray[] = $curProduct;
}
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Following which, you probably need to parse the JSON client-side using:

```
.success(function(response) {
    response = jQuery.parseJSON(response)
    $.each(response, function(index,value){
        ...
    });
});
```

because you're retrieving multiple products at the same time, a foreach loop is required to iterate through all the products and populate your form accordingly.

Comment: you mean like this `success(function(response = jQuery.parseJSON(response))`